# EB AWS leader_only, what happens on EC2 replacement?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops

Any update on this matter anyone ?

https://repost.aws/questions/QU36ieoyXnTrCC8UYMxPFxOg/elastic-beanstalk-eb-is-command-leader-during-instance-replacement